# Microsoft's Windows Media Player plugin doesn't register on Chrome (Windows)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, plugins, windows-media-player, browser-plugin

After installing the "Windows Media Player plug-in for Firefox" (either automatically or by downloading wmpfirefoxplugin.exe manually) and running it, the WMP plugin still does not appear in `about:plugins` and doesn't function.

How can it be fixed?

- The platform is Windows 7 x64 but it might apply to x86 as well.
- This might only occur on systems without any Firefox installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions:

1. Make sure the plugin (`np-mswmp.dll`) was installed into `C:\PFiles\Plugins`. (If not, find where it was installed.)
2. Create the following registry key on 64-bit Windows:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/mswmp`

   or on 32-bit Windows:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@microsoft.com/mswmp`
3. Under this registry entry, create a String value named "`Path`" with the value `C:\PFiles\Plugins\np-mswmp.dll` (or wherever the np-mswmp.dll was installed).
4. In Chrome, go to `about:plugins` and press Reload. You should be able to find "Microsoft® Windows Media Player Firefox Plugin" in the list.

Comment: awesome - been bugged by this a long time, this works

Answer (score 2):

As the follow-up to the question that I found when facing a similar problem. I found another way to fix this: just install the [Interoperability plugin](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/wmp-extension-for-chrome) and everything starts working.

Comment: Ah, there's an official solution now. Great!